# How does an ASP.Net Core Blazor page know to refresh it's contents after an async data getter method returns?

Tags: asp.net, blazor

The question is not how to get it working, it works. I am just interested but can't find out what goes on in the background to make it work.

Prime example is the standard Blazor server webapp template, which has a "counter" and a "fetchdata" component.
In the fetchdata component, there is `protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()` that gets called, and the component renders itself. If the OnInitializedAsync() does not return in time, the render still happens, in the example just writing out loading... Then when the OnInitializedAsync() actually finishes, the component is magically re-rendered, but what caused the re-render? how is it wired together?

Does the framework peek at the class' memory every so often to figure out if a rerender is needed? Is it just that there is a call for the page render before the OnInitializedAsync() call and one after awaiting it?

Comment: Was thinking exactly the same thing and google brought me to this question exactly as I would have worded it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all based on async programming...

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{        
    forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
}
```

The OnInitializedAsync method you've mentioned has two parts: synchronous and asynchronous. When the OnInitializedAsync method starts executing, a call to the awaitable GetForecastAsync method is made, control is yielded to the calling code, Blazor runtime, that starts rendering the UI without delay. This is the first time your component is rendered. This is also why you must check in code that the forecasts variable is not null. When GetForecastAsync returns and the forecasts variable is populated, more code (if exists)  is executed to the end of the method, after which your component re-renders again, this time forecasts is not null, and thus the table is rendered. Of course, this was a simplistic explanation. You can inspect the process, step by step, by viewing the code that does this: [It all starts here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs#L214). It shouldn't be difficult to follow. No magic

Hope this helps...

Comment: Didn`t occur to me that I can directly check the source, but it is much clearer now, how the ComponentBase class behaves. Also, the source is  very thoroughly commented!

Comment: OK the above answer explains things clearly but looking at this chart https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0  first impressions of the render flow there suggest it would only render once.

Comment: @Frank, you should not believe me, not event Steve Anderson or any one else's for that. You should test it yourself. It's easy. Just create a Server Blazor App, override the life cycles methods and execute Console.WriteLine("put identifying text here");  In a couple of minutes you'll know the truth. Just be weary that the default template for Blazor  Server App is re-rendered by default; that is some of the code is executed twice. Thank you for the link. It's time to refresh my knowledge.